# Solitaire all cards dealt face up in 13 columns, then 12, then 11, 10, 9

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I’m trying to figure out the name of this card game.

First turn: Deal out 52 cards, all face up in 13 columns (4 rows). The cards in each column overlap. Can move single cards only. A card can be moved by placing card of same suit in descending order (6 of hearts can be placed on top of 7 of hearts). Kings cannot be moved. Aces get moved to foundation stacks. The goal is to stack by suit Ace-King on the four foundation stacks.

Second turn: first column gets placed on top of second, second on top of third and so forth (all face up). Re-deal In 12 columns. Same rules apply.

Third turn is 11 columns. Fourth is 10 columns and final turn is 9 columns.

I can’t seem to find the name of it or where I could download it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the same rules but it is very similar to [Perseverance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(solitaire))

- It's a solitaire game starting with 12 columns, not 13 (the 4 aces are moved to the foundations at the beginning)
- You have to build the foundation from ace to king
- you can only stack cards of the same suit in the columns
- when you are stuck you pile the columns without shuffling and re-deal in less columns. Not specifically 13, 12, 11, 10, 9 as you mentioned but in pile of 4 cards.